# Keeping Method called in another Method inside the same Worker Thread

Tags: c#, threadpool

If you are calling a method (M1) using a QueueUserWorkItem, why is it that when M1 calls another method (M2) inside of it, M2 is ran on the Main Thread instead of inside the same Worker Thread as M1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you are calling a method (M1) using a QueueUserWorkItem, why is it
>   that when M1 calls another method (M2) inside of it, M2 is ran on the
>   Main Thread instead of inside the same Worker Thread as M1?

That is not a true statement, the method M2 will be called by the same thread as M1 (unless i.e. you  specifically queue up the call to M2 for execution on another thread, i.e. using a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx))

Comment: I guess I didn't give enough details although I figured out what I was doing wrong. Basically M2 was being invoked via a Listview which would explain why it was appearing in the main thread. The method that M1 was calling was another method entirely which all it does is invoke M2 if invoke is required. Thanks for clearing it up anyway.